# CALayer fade from current value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

My app uses `CALayer` to draw views. More precisely, it uses the `drawLayer:inContext:` method on a sublayer of a `UIView`'s top layer. This is a nice way to get the 'implicit' animation of consecutive `drawLayer:inContext:` drawings to fade into each other over time. The fading animations happen fairly fast, maybe in 0.25 seconds, but to change its duration, simply implement another delegate method called `actionForLayer:forKey:`. In this perfectly working example implementation here the default duration is stretched to 2.0 seconds:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event];
    animation.duration = 2.0;
    return animation;

    // or return nil for the default duration.
}
```

On to the issue at hand.

If you call `[sublayer setNeedsDisplay]` faster than the fades have time to complete, with each new fade you'll see a sudden jump. From the looks of it, the fade that's in progress is cancelled and it's final state is used as the starting point of the new fade. This might not be very surprising, but the visual result is rather unwanted.

Consider the scenario of a ten second fade from black to white, with another fade, to black, triggered five seconds after the start. The animation will start fading from black to white, but when it's at a 'half way gray' it jumps to full white before fading to black again.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Can I get the layer to fade from the gray back down to black? Is there a CALayer drawing equivalent of saying `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` (used in UIView animations)?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A layer's animation is only a visual representation of what the layer should look like as it animates. In CA when you animate from one state to another, the entire state of the layer changes immediately. A presentation layer is created and displays the animation, and when the animation completes the actual layer is left in place at the end.

*So,* my guess is that when you want to transition from one state to another, and the current animation hasn't completed yet, you have to capture the current state of the animation and then use this as the starting point for your next animation.

The problem lies in not being able to modify a layer's current animation.

In the following post I capture the current state of an animation, set that as the current state for the layer and use that as the beginning value from which to animate. The post applies this technique to the speed / duration of an animation, but can also be applied to your scenario.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544674/1218605

Comment: P.S. This post helped me find a bug in my own API that I'm developing... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little stumped on this one too.

Did you forget to specify the fillMode `kCAFillModeForwards`. There's more info about that [in the reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming).

For example, I got this to work without any snapping, although I'm not changing the duration.

```
@implementation FadingLayer

- (void)fadeOut {    
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.fromValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    animation.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    animation.delegate = self;    
    [self addAnimation:animation
                    forKey:@"test"];
}

- (void)fadeIn {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.fromValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
    animation.toValue = (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    animation.delegate = self;    
    [self addAnimation:animation
                    forKey:@"test"];
}

@end
```

You'll probably want to animate [a custom property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming) however.

Hope this helps :/

Comment: Because I'm using `drawLayer:inContext:` of which the fading is animated implicitly, setting the kCAFillModeForwards property does not help. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to accomplish the same thing with a zoom animation of a layer tree. I have a zoom in/out key-equivalent where the user can zoom the layer tree accordingly. However, if the user presses the zoom key-equivalent in rapid succession, there would be a temporary snap-back to the values prior to the onset of the animation, since the previous animation hadn't yet completed.

At the end of the animation code, performing a sole `[CATransaction commit]` forced any pending transactions to be committed to the layer model before the start of the next animation, and solved the problem.

The documentation says:

> + commit
>
> Commit all changes made during the current transaction.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> + (void)commit
>
> **Special Considerations**
>
> Raises an exception if no current transaction exists.

However, testing this with many `[CATransaction commit]` messages in succession doesn't actually raise an exception. I've used this same technique to squelch warnings of the form:

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted
>   CATransaction;

in an NSOperation whose thread of execution finishes before layer animations do. It could be that Apple changed this behaviour in recent OS releases to a no-op (which would be much saner) if no current transaction exists, without updating the documentation.